# How do I use kml placemarker from file?

Tags: kml

```
<href>drive location</href>
```

doesn't work, quite naturally.  I haven't seen anywhere that actually addresses how to reference a hard drive location as where the placemark image is to be taken from.  What is line of code I have to use to bring in an image from a hard drive?

Comment: href in context of iconStyle, overlay or networkLink ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  `<href>` tag in KML is used to represent a **URL** to the file location not the Windows absolute file location so `http://server/myimage.png` is valid but `c:/myfiles/image.png` is not.

First try moving the image to the same folder as the KML file and refer to the image via a relative URL with just the filename.

Example:

```
  <Style>
      <IconStyle>
         <Icon>
            <href>icon21.png</href>
         </Icon>
      </IconStyle>
  </Style>
```

If want to represent an absolute file location as a URL then *C:\myimages\image.png* can be rewritten as *file:///C:/mymages/image.png*.

Comment: I had tried it similarly but never even thought to add the file:// to the beginning of the file location.  Thanks for the help.